# Confusing behaviour of xslant in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I now want to draw two slanted grids on top of each other.

This is a minimal file which gives the wrong result:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[xslant=1] (0,0) grid[step=1] (6,4);   % bottom grid
  \draw[xslant=1] (0,9) grid[step=1] (6,13);  % upper grid
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The "upper" grid is pushed way over to the right, as though the `xslant` in the second command is augmented by the first.  If I change the second draw command to

```
\draw[xslant=0] (0,9) grid[step=1] (6,13);
```

then the grid is drawn in the correct position, but without the slant.

One way of putting it in the correct position is to use

```
\draw[xslant=1] (-9,9) grid[step=1] ++(6,4);
```

as the second draw command, but that seems a bit crazy.  Surely I should be able to start that second grid at (0,9)?

Comment: The manual (PGF 3.0, Section 14.8) states that "All coordinate transformations apply to the grid", so you need to move the origin using `shift` _before_ applying the `xslant` as transformations are additive.

Answer (score 3):

you are using the environment `tikzpicture` which defines the origin of a coordinate system. Both `\draw` commands refer to that origin `(0,0)`. With `[xslant=1]` you have the y coordinate axis slanted and the point `(0,9)` is on that slanted y axis. The output is correct. Compare it with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

%\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikz\draw[xslant=1] (0,0) grid[step=1] (6,4);   % bottom grid
  \tikz\draw[xslant=1] (0,9) grid[step=1] (6,13);  % upper grid
%\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You can use a node to put the single object:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [very thin,color=gray] (0,0) grid (6,13);
  \draw[xslant=1,thick] (0,0) grid[step=1] (6,4);   % bottom grid
  \node at (5,11)  {\tikz\draw[xslant=1,thick] (0,0) grid[step=1] (6,4);};  % upper grid
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

`(5,11)` is the center of the slanted grid. You can also place it with its lower left corner at `(9,0)` which makes no difference.

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  I was under the impression that `xslant` referred only to the command in which it was used.  So I'd get the same result with `\begin{tikzpicture}[xslant=1]`.  Is there any variant of `xslant` which can be used to draw a slanted grid, but whose scope is its command?

Comment: Also, in your example, since the two `\tikz` commands are treated by LaTeX as separate entities, they are drawn next to each other, rather than one above the other.  My diagram will have several different sized slanted grids in it, all of which need to be placed in reference to each other.

Comment: see my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what works:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[xslant=1] (0,0) grid ++(6,4);
    \draw[shift={(0,9)},xslant=1] (0,0) grid ++(6,4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

It seems that `shift` works independently of `xslant`.